# Как передать картинку сгенерированную PIL через POST запрос?

Tags: python, pil

Как передать картинку сгенерированную в PIL через POST запрос в формате multipart/form-data. 
Вот код передачи изображения

```
requests.post(upload_url, files = {'file': open(filename, 'rb')})
```

Задача заключается в передачи изображения без его сохранения как отдельного файла.

Пробовал через BytesIO. Не получается.

```
img = pic_gen.gen_obj(parcer.main()) #Создаю изображение

buf = io.BytesIO()
img.save(buf, format='PNG')
buf.seek(0, 0)
#a = io.BufferedReader(buf)
album_id = ID альбома
group_id = ID группы


token = 'ТОКЕН'
api = vk.API(vk.Session(access_token=token), v=5.92)
upload_url = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=group_id)['upload_url'] 
resp = requests.post(upload_url, files = {'file': buf.getvalue()}).json() 
s = api.photos.saveWallPhoto(group_id=group_id, server = resp['server'], photo= resp['photo'], hash = resp['hash'])
api.wall.post(owner_id = -group_id, message="Test!", attachments=f"photo{s[0]['owner_id']}_{s[0]['id']}")
```

Comment: Сохранить картинку как в файл, только не в файл, а в объект `io.BytesIO`

Comment: Я пробовал, но это не работает.

Comment: Я тоже пробовал, и у меня это работает в течение последних трёх лет. Значит вы как-то не так пробовали, не расскажете как?

Comment: Возможно у меня какой-то частный случай. Я загружаю картинку через POST запрос VK API. Когда я использую конструкцию для открытия файла, то всё работает. Но когда заменяю на io.BytesIO то выдаёт ошибку. 
P.S. Если подскажете как добавить код в коментарий, то буду благодарен

Comment: Текст ошибки — большой секрет? Добавьте код в текст вопроса, а не в комментарий.

Comment: 100. One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid. request_params = {'oauth': '1', 'method': 'photos.saveWallPhoto', 'v': '5.92', 'group_id': 'ID группы', 'server': 'ID сервера', 'photo': '[]', 'hash': 'ХЭШ'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new('RGB', (128, 128), (255, 0, 0, 255))
# [вставить сюда код усердного рисования картинки]

fp = BytesIO()
im.save(fp, format='PNG')

# Переключаем позицию чтения в начало файла, чтобы
# requests смог его прочитать
fp.seek(0)

requests.post(
    upload_url,
    # Капризные серверы могут запросить имя файла
    # и MIME-тип — укажем их
    # (для JPEG соответственно нужно указать image/jpeg)
    files={'file': ('photo.png', fp, 'image/png')},
)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. 3-й день бьюсь над решением. И правда, всё упиралось в MIME.